# Who starts kodi on ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, startup-applications, kodi

Not sure this question is good here or if I should ask on ubuntu forum...
I'm trying to write a script that restarts kodi via cli, so I need to know how to launch it once it stopped.
In my ubuntu 16.04 there are a lot of processes related to kodi:

```
fmf@kodi:~$ ps ax|grep kodi
1142 ?        Ss     0:16 avahi-daemon: running [kodi.local]
1638 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/kodi-standalone
1730 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch kodi-standalone
1733 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch kodi-standalone
1747 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/kodi --standalone
1749 ?        Sl   200:14 /usr/lib/kodi/kodi.bin --standalone
24195 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto kodi
fmf@kodi:~$
```

The problem is that I don't know why all those processes are there and which script/startup command/init process is responsible of launching kodi and creating all those processes.
Can please someone help me identify all those processes?

Assuming that I managed to stop kodi somehow, how do I start it without rebooting the computer?

Comment: Depends on how it is being started. Kodi doesn't run a root, so it is usually the user that is logged in.

Comment: How kodi is being started is exactly the topic of my original question...

Comment: Ah, my reply was based off the title to your question - "Who starts kodi on ubuntu?" I've added a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting KODI is easy! All you have to do is kill the KODI process, and it'll start back up on its own.

```
    $> sudo kill -s 9 `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep kodi | awk '{print $2}'`
```

That's it!